# Unable to capture the snap using intent - Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to add a code in my current app so that on one button click ,camera should open and one snap should be taken.

here is my code :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        try {
            PackageManager pm =this.getPackageManager();

            final ResolveInfo mInfo = pm.resolveActivity(i, 0);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(mInfo.activityInfo.packageName, mInfo.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

            startActivity(intent); 
        } 

catch (Exception e){ Log.i(TAG, "Unable to launch camera: " + e); }
```

**Error : it displays -> Complete action uing**

Not able to figure it out what i am doin wrong, can any one help me out in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Add permission to your manifest

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="fase" />
```

**Second**

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //Your code

   //dispatchTakePictureIntent() <-- call this on some button click etc.
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

**Third**

Retrieve your Snap

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

> Retrieved Image is only a small size thumbnail. To get/save full size Image